# auto select of h:checkbox in jsf datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2

I have a datatable in which first and second column is checkbox , first one is multiselect and second one id single select, I have done till this,
Now I have to auto select the first chckbox when user click the second checkbox which is for default .
as I am new to javascript please assist.
below is my datatable

```
<h:dataTable value="#{roundingBean.elementDetailsDTOList}" var="v"  styleClass="updateitem">
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header"> Select</f:facet>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkBox" value="#{v.isCheckBoxSelected}"  />
</h:column>

<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header"> Default Category</f:facet>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="radio" value="#{v.isRadioSelected}"  onclick="dataTableSelectOneRadio(this);"/> 
</h:column>

<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header"> Category</f:facet>
        #{v.categoryName}
    </h:column>
```

Comment: a fiddle will be more helpful...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkBox" value="#{v.isCheckBoxSelected}" onclick="document.getElementById("radio").checked = true;" />
```

Comment: You need to debug your self. Look in the source of your browser, see if the id is really radio, and change that accordingly. It should work, but you have to do some work too

Answer (score 0):

You will have to take help of css and jquery here.
If you have a unique id variable in ElementDetailsDTO, use it to define a css class for the checkbox.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkBox" value="#{v.isCheckBoxSelected}" styleClass="#{v.id}StyleClass" />
```

Then for the radio button, add an onselect attribute like below

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="radio" value="#{v.isRadioSelected}"  onclick="$('.#{v.id}StyleClass').prop('checked',true)"/>
```

Using id attribute to get elements inside a data table is not advisable since in the actual html that is generated, these ids will be prefixed with the table id and column id.